# Chrome inline extension on verified site throws error: No Chrome Web Store item link found

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have followed the deployment instruction of an inline installation of my extension on a site that I have verified.

```
<link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jakgfopmadhihjajjegmbnaiimjbmdlk">
```

And for the button:

```
<a href="javascript:chrome.webstore.install();">Install me</a>
```

But when I press the button i get this strange error:

```
Uncaught No Chrome Web Store item link found.
```

Comment: Did you put the `<link rel="chrome-webstore-item">` **in the `<head>`**?

Comment: Also experiencing this. Yes, the <link> is in the <head>. :)

Comment: Did you click the "This item uses inline install." checkbox during the webstore publishing step?

Comment: Remember to whitelist your website in the chrome webstore dashboard.

Answer (score 4):

I know the question is very old but in case if someone else is facing:

You need to provide the URL and call back functions in the function `chrome.webstore.install()`.

Here is the code:

in the `<head>` put `<link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jakgfopmadhihjajjegmbnaiimjbmdlk">`

and call via javascript:

```
chrome.webstore.install('https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jakgfopmadhihjajjegmbnaiimjbmdlk', 
    function(d){
       console.log('installed')
    },
    function(e){
       console.log('not installed: '+ e)
    });
```

**Source**: https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation